# Using dataframe values to query SQL database and appending back into dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a dataframe that I can draw values from to write a query for a sql database and want to append the queried information on that dataframe. The original dataframe would be something like:

df =

```
ID YEAR CODE 
43 2013 051
97 2015 087
...
```

and my current code being:

```
import pypyodbc as podbc

db = podbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=server;Database=database')

for row in df:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    query = '''
    SELECT ID, Tool, Date, Version
    FROM table
    WHERE ID = '{id}'
    AND Year(Date) = '{year}'
    AND Code = '{code}'
    '''.format(id = df.ID, year = df.YEAR, code = df.CODE)

    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=[x[0] for x in cursor.description)
```

The returned value from a single query is like:

```
    ID   Tool   Date         Version
0   43   C15    22-05-2013   1.0
```

So my issues right now are

```
1. I don't know how to create an iterable query (for row in df)
2. I don't know how to relate the new dataframe that the query creates to the original df
```

Hopefully the result would be something like:

```
ID YEAR CODE Tool Date        Version
43 2013 051  C15  22-05-2013  1.0
97 2015 087  C67  31-01-2015  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already using pandas,

Try this,

```
conn = podbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=server;Database=database')

query = ''' SELECT ID, Tool, Date, Version 
            FROM table 
            WHERE ID = '{id}' AND 
            Year(Date) = '{year}' AND 
            Code = '{code}' '''.replace("\n","").format(id = df.ID, year = df.YEAR, code = df.CODE)

df = pd.read_sql(query,conn)
    # For large datasets use chunks=chunk_size, low_memory=False
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add space at the end of every line of query.

Comment: This method definitely works for reading the query, but I run into the same thing as before, where it will not return values for the whole table with this query

Comment: @RoyHan What ever the output you get after executing query on server. You will get that all as output for `pd.read_sql()`. Did you checked the query on database?

Comment: the query works where 
   query = '''
    SELECT ID, Tool, Date, Version
    FROM table
    WHERE ID = '43'
    AND Year(Date) = '2013'
    AND Code = '051'
    '''
but not where 
    query = '''
    SELECT ID, Tool, Date, Version
    FROM table
    WHERE ID = '{id}'
    AND Year(Date) = '{year}'
    AND Code = '{code}'
    '''.format(id = df.ID, year = df.YEAR, code = df.CODE)

Comment: @RoyHan, Answer was updated. Please check now and confirm.